# How can i change de display of a div as i hover over the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a div that acts as a parent and has a background image and a child div whith a text. I want my child div to be displayed none and a i hover over the parent div the child is now visible. How can i achieve this?

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className="main_img sunglasses_container">
            <div className="cta cta_sunglasses">Sunglasses</div>
        </div>
        <div className="main_img perfumes_container">
            <div className="cta cta_perfumes">Perfumes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

And this are my styles:

```
/*Main container*/

.container{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 70vh;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
   transition: 0.3s ease;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}


.main_img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;

}

.sunglasses_container{
   background-image: url("../images/sunglasses.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   margin-right: 3px;
}

.sunglasses_container:hover,
.perfumes_container:hover{
   opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Target the cta div that comes after the hovered sunglasses_container div */
.sunglasses_container:hover ~ .cta_sunglasses{
   display: flex;
}

.perfumes_container{
   background-image: url("../images/perfumes.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   margin-left: 3px;
}

/* Target the cta div that comes after the hovered perfumes_container div */
.perfumes_container:hover ~ .cta_perfumes{
   display: flex;
}

.cta{
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
}

.cta_sunglasses, .cta_perfumes{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 24px;
   display: none;
}
```

I tried targetting the child div using the `~` operator but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ is used to target a sibling of the target. You can use:

```
.perfumes_container:hover .cta_perfumes{
    display: flex;
}
```

So without ~